# array is not returning value for given key

Tags: php

I am using the following PHP code...

```
$settings[] = get_app_settings();
echo $settings['weight_unit'];
```

but its throwing error 'undefined index'.

and when i do `print_r($settings);` it generates following...

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [support_email] => info@domain.com [support_phone] => 9812345678 [currency_symbol] => $ [weight_unit] => g. [catalogue_image_width] => 450 [catalogue_image_height] => 675 [single_product_image_width] => 500 [single_product_image_height] => 500 [product_image_width] => 200 [product_image_height] => 200 [tax_rate] => 1 [shipping_charges] => 0 ) )
```

Why is it not returning a value for `$settings['weight_unit'];` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its solved by removing `[]`(array) from `$settings`. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Try `$settings = get_app_settings();` - you probably want to assign the returned array directly and not to a new array element in `$settings`.